# How to make zero the entire row except the first column, if it has a zero in any other colum in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I would like to make zero the entire row except first column, if it has a zero value in any other column. e.g.,

```
ifile.txt
1   4.5   9
2   5.0   0
3   2.4   4
4   3.1   2
5   0.0   0
6   2.4   1
7   0.0   5

I am looking my output as

ofile.txt
1   4.5   9
2   0.0   0
3   2.4   4
4   3.1   2
5   0.0   0
6   2.4   1
7   0.0   0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the columns in your input file are separated by tabs:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ if ($2 == 0 || $3 == 0) { $2 = 0; $3 = 0 }; printf("%d\t%.1f\t%d\n", $1, $2, $3) }' ifile.txt
```

Output:

```
1       4.5     9
2       0.0     0
3       2.4     4
4       3.1     2
5       0.0     0
6       2.4     1
7       0.0     0
```

Comment: You don't have to specify the `FS`, the default is any whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '!$2{$3=0} !$3{$2="0.0"} 1' file
1   4.5   9
2 0.0 0
3   2.4   4
4   3.1   2
5 0.0 0
6   2.4   1
7 0.0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash (and bc) and for an arbitrary number of columns:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat in.txt)
do
    found_zero=
    zeros=
    IFS=$' '
    # Find if zero in any column, and generate columns with zeros
    for e in ${line#* }
    do
        (( $(bc <<< "$e == 0.0") == 1 )) && found_zero=1
        zeros="$zeros 0.0"
    done
    # If found zero in a column, write only zeros
    if [ $found_zero ]
    then
        echo "${line%% *}$zeros"
    else
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/$/ /;/[[:space:]]\(0\.\)\{0,1\}0[[:space:]]/!b o
s/\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1 0.0 0/
:o
s/ $//' YourFile
```

with formating column

```
sed 's/$/ /;/[[:space:]]\(0\.\)\{0,1\}0[[:space:]]/!b o
h;s/[[:space:]].*//;x;s/[^[:space:]]*//;s/[1-9]/0/g;H;x;s/\n//
:o
s/ $//' YourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

This achieves your desired outcome, while preserving white space:

```
gawk '!($2*$3) {$0 = gensub(/([[:space:].])[0-9]/,"\\10", "g")} 1' ifile.txt
```

Explanation:

- Condition: `!($2*$3)` : If one of the 2nd or 3rd fields is zero (0) then their product will be zero
- If the condition is true, replace all digits `[0-9]` which come after a space or dot `[[:space:].]` with zero (0)
- `\\10` : is actually `\1` + `0` : meaning print the first match (the space or dot), followed by a literal zero (0)

If you want to make it work for an arbitrary number of fields, e.g. for the following input:

```
$ cat ifile_ext.txt
1   4.5   3.2   .5   1.9   2.0   9
2   5.0   6.4   .1   0.0   3.4   0
3   2.4   4.1   .4   2.3   1.0   4
4   3.1   2.0   .6   1.3   2.4   2
5   0.0   1.0   .9   2.3   0.0   0
6   2.4   2.0   .1   4.5   1.2   1
7   0.0   4.5   .2   9.4   0.0   5
8   1.0   2.0   .0   1.2   4.1   1
```

Then you have to loop over the fields, and then perform the same transformation:

```
gawk '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if (!$i) {$0 = gensub(/([[:space:].])[0-9]/,"\\10", "g")} } 1'  ifile_ext.txt
```

Output:

```
1   4.5   3.2   .5   1.9   2.0   9
2   0.0   0.0   .0   0.0   0.0   0
3   2.4   4.1   .4   2.3   1.0   4
4   3.1   2.0   .6   1.3   2.4   2
5   0.0   0.0   .0   0.0   0.0   0
6   2.4   2.0   .1   4.5   1.2   1
7   0.0   0.0   .0   0.0   0.0   0
8   0.0   0.0   .0   0.0   0.0   0
```